# Is Redis 4 supported with Spinnaker?

Tags: redis, migration, upgrade, spinnaker

Running redis 3 currently and works fine. Would like to upgrade to Redis 4 and looking to see If anyone is running Spinnaker with Redis 4.

Comment: https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/storage/redis/

Answer (score 0):

The Redis storage implementation is untested and unsupported by anyone in the Spinnaker community.

Comment: hmm... yeah, I saw that link. Its works perfectly fine with Redis 3. Wondering, why that is no at least updated. Anyways, I will test with Redis 4 and update the answer. thanks.

Comment: To be clear, Redis is unsupported when used as a persistence mechanism. Not sure if that's what you're referring to. Redis is absolutely supported (required) for its caching mechanism. We haven't tested it with Redis 4, however.